# Create compressed GeoTiff in Java

Tags: convert, java, geotiff-tiff, geotools, esri-ascii-raster

I've got a typical two-dimensional array in Java with values which represent a grid. Rows, columns, coordinate system (latlon), origin and cell size are known. I am able to export this data as ASCII Grid but I need to create a compressed GeoTiff. And I would like to stay in the Java world, so doing it with gdal_translate is straight forward but not the solution I am looking for.

I found GeoTools [GeoTiffWriterTest.java](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/geotiff_new/src/test/java/org/geotools/gce/geotiff/GeoTiffWriterTest.java) but am not able to extract the main part I need.

Comment: There are [Java bindings for GDAL](http://gdal.org/java/) which enable you to access the GDAL API from within Java.

Comment: Why extract from GeoTools? can't you just use it as is?

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I found a great demo in the [geotools mailing list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Creating-GeoTiff-from-an-int-td4322528.html). Cheers.